# C# Setup issues

Tags: c#, setup-project

I created a setup file for c# windows application. When installing this setup and launching application it fails and giving following exceptions.
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at TouchStation.TouchStationProfile.WriteToRegistry()
   at TouchStation.TouchStationProfile.SetAsCurrent()
   at TouchStation.Program.writeSettingsToRegistry()
   at TouchStation.Program.Initialize()
   at TouchStation.MainForm.statusUpdateTimer_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5472 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
TouchStation
    Assembly Version: 2.0.1.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.1.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/TouchStation2.0.1.0/TouchStation.exe
----------------------------------------
TouchCommonLib
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/TouchStation2.0.1.0/TouchCommonLib.DLL
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5467 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
ThingzDB
    Assembly Version: 1.3.1.0
    Win32 Version: 1.3.1.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/TouchStation2.0.1.0/ThingzDB.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5468 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5467 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
TouchServerLib
    Assembly Version: 0.9.2.0
    Win32 Version: 0.9.2.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/TouchStation2.0.1.0/TouchServerLib.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5476 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5476 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
WindowsHookLib
    Assembly Version: 1.1.1.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.4
    CodeBase: file:///C:/TouchStation2.0.1.0/WindowsHookLib.DLL
----------------------------------------
Accessibility
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Accessibility/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data.SQLite
    Assembly Version: 1.0.66.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.66.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/TouchStation2.0.1.0/System.Data.SQLite.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.EnterpriseServices
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_32/System.EnterpriseServices/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Please help.

Regards
Sangeetha

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: Well it looks like   your program is crashing in its write to registry section.  Does the key exist?